# pgfkeys pass font command

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

I am defining options using the `pgfkeys` command.

```
\newcommand{\subtitlefont}{}
\pgfkeys{
   /titleblock/.is family, /titleblock,
   default/.style = 
       {titlesize = 48, titlelineskip = 52,
        subtitlesize = 36, subtitlelineskip = 39, subtitlefont=\itshape,
       },
   titlesize/.estore in = \titlesize,
   titlelineskip/.estore in = \titlelineskip,
   subtitlesize/.estore in = \subtitlesize,
   subtitlelineskip/.estore in = \subtitlelineskip,
   subtitlefont/.add code={}{\subtitlefont},
}
```

Them I want to use this options in a node font option.

```
\node[align=left, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
 font={\fontsize{\subtitlesize}{\subtitlelineskip}\subtitlefont\selectfont},
 text=\titleblockcolor,
 below= 0.1cm of title.south west, anchor=north west] (subtitle) {
   \thesubtitle%
   };
```

The document compiles but the `\itshape` is not selected for the subtitle.
What is the best way to define an option that consist in macros that can be passed to a node option?

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\subtitlefont}{}
\pgfkeys{
   /titleblock/.is family, /titleblock,
   default/.style = 
       {
         subtitlesize = 36, subtitlelineskip = 39, subtitlefont=\itshape,
       },
   subtitlesize/.estore in = \subtitlesize,
   subtitlelineskip/.estore in = \subtitlelineskip,
   subtitlefont/.add code={}{\subtitlefont},
}



\newcommand{\titleblock}[1][]{%
\pgfkeys{/titleblock, default, #1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=left, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
  font={\fontsize{\subtitlesize}{\subtitlelineskip}\subtitlefont\selectfont},
  text=black] (subtitle) {A nice title};
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\begin{document}
\titleblock
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a minimal (non) working example.

Comment: Before anything, you shouldn't `/.estore` them.

Comment: In addition to what percusse told, add `subtitlefont/.store in=\subtitlefont,` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I don't know why I was using `estore in`. That didn't work, but  `store in` is working. If you make the comment an asnwer I can select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `pgfmanual` page, 889

[image]

Hence you should be using `store in` instead of `estore in`. Also use `subtitlefont/.add code={}{\subtitlefont},` instead of `subtitlefont/.store in=\subtitlefont,`.  Adding to this, since you are using large font sizes, it is better to use `lmodern` package which provides nice scalable fonts and you wouldn't get warnings.

With these your code becomes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\subtitlefont}{}
\pgfkeys{
   /titleblock/.is family, /titleblock,
   default/.style =
       {
         subtitlesize = 36, subtitlelineskip = 39, subtitlefont=\itshape,
       },
   subtitlesize/.store in = \subtitlesize,
   subtitlelineskip/.store in = \subtitlelineskip,
   subtitlefont/.store in=\subtitlefont,
}



\newcommand{\titleblock}[1][]{%
\pgfkeys{/titleblock, default, #1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=left, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
  font={\fontsize{\subtitlesize}{\subtitlelineskip}\subtitlefont\selectfont},
  text=black] (subtitle) {A nice title};
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\begin{document}
\titleblock
\end{document}
```

[image]